# What was the biggest chess tournament held in the world?

Tags: history, tournament, records

Which chess tournament and venue has brought in the most people in the world?

Comment: Hi Lance, I edited your question to make it more about tournaments that have already happened.  Stack Exchange is good for questions that have definitive answers, but it is not as good for open ended questions.  I think you will still get answers to your open ended question, but feel free to edit if the meaning of your question was lost as well!

Comment: @Andrew, while I thought it was asking for something pretty definitive, I'm fine with it the way you edited it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it was the [Cebu Chess Festival-World’s Largest Chess Tournament](http://www.chessblog.com/2011/11/cebu-city-efforts-on-for-attempt-at.html) held in Ahmedabad, an Indian state, in December 2010. It had 20000 players and was led by Anand.

Answer (score 7):

The [Guinness world record for the largest board game tournament](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/largest-board-game-tournament) consisted of 43,157 participants playing chess and was achieved by the Cebu City Sports Commission (Philippines) in Cebu, Philippines, on 22 January 2012.

Hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

According to the USCF, the record holder for largest attendance at a rated chess competition is the SuperNationals V with 5335 participants. [Link](http://www.uschess.org/content/view/12160/707/)

The SuperNationals III also had over 5000 participants, so this must be the recurring tournament that brings in the most people.

Answer (score 3):

We run the annual [South African Junior Chess Championships](https://www.sajcc.co.za/about/) -

> The history of this tournament dates back more than 30 years and the
> tournament typically attracts in excess of 2,500 junior chess players
> and officials

Comment: If we restrict to juniors, this has to compete with Hamburg's "Linkes gegen Rechtes Alsterufer", also a traditional event. Wiki (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechtes_Alsterufer_gegen_Linkes_Alsterufer#Teilnehmer) gives over 4000 participants as record.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is the Olympiad -- in the last edition, [Istanbul 2012](http://www.chessolympiadistanbul.com/), 150 countries participated in the Open, and 127 in the Women section. Most of those teams had 5 players (some had 4), so that's about 1300 players I'd guess. This year's Olympiad will be held in [Tromsø, Norway](http://tromso2014.no/).

Comment: Most countries? Sure. Most players? Probably not, only so many countries/teams in the world